# What caused the shape of Jean Jacket to be altered in Nope?

Tags: plot-explanation, nope

We see during the final chapter of the movie, that the shape of Jean Jacket changed from its previous saucer shape to a jellyfish-like appearance. Was there a particular reason why it happened, indicated in the events leading up to that scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to Collider](https://collider.com/nope-alien-jean-jacket-explained/):

> During the climactic end of the film, Jean Jacket unravels into a Kleenex-thin indescribable swirl. The implication of the story is that **this is a form the creature takes when threatened**, similar to a lizard extending its facial frills to intimidate or a peacock spreading its feathers to show off to potential mates.

The article goes on to speculate:

> This particular look seems to take inspiration from Biblical depictions of angels. In the first chapter of his book, the prophet Ezekiel describes Ophanim, a kind of angel composed of four interlocking wheels. Traditional artistic renderings of them resemble Jean Jacket’s frilled, circle-obsessed form. Nope likely intends to imply that, like sightings of flying saucers, angelic encounters can be explained by this creature’s appearance.

---

[Screenrant's explanation](https://screenrant.com/nope-movie-alien-change-form-reason/) follows the first explanation:

> Explanations given throughout the film might explain why Jean Jacket changes shape at the end. While a full explanation of *Nope*'s alien and UFO is never shared, its predatory nature hints at the startling change. Jean Jacket's behavior is similar to deimatic behavior in creatures like octopi. When threatened, **octopi may make themselves appear much larger and camouflage themselves in order to frighten away predators.** In fact, "deimatic" originates from a Greek term that means "to frighten." The behavior is typically reserved for prey or threatened animals, perhaps suggesting that despite its imposing presence, the alien is intimidated.

Answer (score 2):

It's related to or a reference to the behavior of the real-life animals that were the inspiration for Jean Jacket. Its final form references the "[Angels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_in_Neon_Genesis_Evangelion)" in the anime series, *Neon Genesis Evangelion*.

One of the scientific consultants for the film, John O. Dabiri, was interviewed about the creature's design:

> [...] John O. Dabiri, an engineering professor at CalTech whose research studies animal behavior and fluid dynamics to create new technologies.
>
> In a phone conversation with Thrillist, Dabiri went in depth on how he and Peele's team created this creature, which animal behaviors they used for inspiration, and whether there could be more Jean Jackets hiding in plain sight amongst the clouds.

> **Thrillist:** I love anything creature-related, and I was so happy that there was no twist that was like, "well, actually, it's this thing." It's just a beast coming after you!
>
> **Dabiri:** [...] I took them down to our lab here at CalTech. **When we feed our jellyfish, they have what are called oral arms, which are these almost silk-like ribbons that end up getting released and displayed when they're feeding. It's really cool to see the analogy between feeding time in my lab, when we put little tiny baby shrimp in there and they all get pulled and caught with the tentacles, versus what you see at the end of the movie, that same type of unfurling of Jean Jacket.**

> **Thrillist:** Do you remember any other specific creatures that you used for inspiration?
>
> **Dabiri:** **Yeah—jellyfish and squid and octopus, a lot of these marine species.** There's other types of jellyfish that maybe don't immediately come to your mind. When you think of a jellyfish, you're probably thinking of the umbrella-shaped animals, but there are other jellyfish shapes that actually don't have this really dramatic body motion as they're swimming. They are almost like a rigid object. Instead, they have these rows of really thin hairs that paddle the water around them. They're typically called [comb jellies](https://www.montereybayaquarium.org/animals/animals-a-to-z/comb-jelly), like a hair comb. In those species, you get this behavior where they move very quietly or stealthily through the water. They don't disturb a lot of the water around them when they're attacking their prey.
>
> **In the first part of the movie, you're just seeing glimpses of Jean Jacket. It doesn't do the really big, dramatic displays until toward the end. Some biological creatures, they do as much as they can to stay under the radar, so to speak, by keeping a pretty rigid shape. And only occasionally, if those comb jellies, for example, are going to eat prey, they will very quickly do that, and then go back to that stealth mode.**

<sup>- [*Inside the Eerie UFO Design for Jordan Peele's 'Nope'* — Thrillist](https://www.thrillist.com/entertainment/nation/nope-movie-ufo-design) (emphasis mine)</sup>

My interpretation of the above quote by one of the creature's designers, is that the "flying saucer" form is the creature's usual, regular form. Only when it got agitated enough by what OJ and co. did, did the creature change to its "angel" form.

> **The anime series Neon Genesis Evangelion has extraterrestrial lifeforms dubbed “Angels” attacking earth.** A few of them show the same geometric patterns that the UFO does, but none of them is a perfect match, but it’s not hard to see the inspiration. **Jordan Peele quoted Evangelion as the principal inspiration for the film and the monster within.**
>
> Peele is a well-known anime fan, so it’s no surprise that he was inspired by one of the most popular anime ever. However, despite the design not having much to do with the biblical description of angels, there might still be a connection. The verse from Nahum that prefaces the film shows Peele was obviously thinking of the bible. If you think about the way the UFO feeds and the concept of people ascending to heaven, it’s not hard to connect the dots. Jean Jacket might have been with humanity for a long time, and an attack from one of the creatures could have been misinterpreted as something from the divine.

<sup>- [*Is the UFO in Nope a Biblically Accurate Angel?* — GameRevolution](https://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/711475-is-nope-ufo-biblically-accurate-angel) (emphasis mine)</sup>

> However, if you were watching "Nope" and felt like one aspect of the film felt pretty familiar, then your intuition was likely correct. When the alien nicknamed Jean Jacket reveals its true form towards the end of the movie, it is a frightening yet oddly beautiful sight that feels almost biblical. **According to the production notes for the film, this final reveal owes itself to the 1995 mecha anime "Neon Genesis Evangelion," a series often attributed as one of the most influential of all time and one that helped to spur international interest in anime.**
>
> The "hyper minimalism" and "biomechanical design flair" of the otherworldly entities known in "Evangelion" as "Angels" were directly cited as one of the influences behind Jean Jacket's design — and it is extremely obvious and welcome.

<sup>- [*This Influential Anime Inspired The Final Alien Design In Nope* — SlashFilm.com](https://www.slashfilm.com/940351/this-influential-anime-inspired-the-final-alien-design-in-nope/) (emphasis mine)</sup>